# BindingSource.Filter ignoring one of my conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, filter, bindingsource

I have a BindingSource filter with multiple conditions. The reason for that is so I could have a **single** search_textbox to find a specific record...

I have one problem though, I have a slightly more permanent condition"**Status LIKE '*{0}*' AND...**", but once I type anything, that restriction is ignored. I assumed the 'AND' would take care of that, but apparently I was mistaken.

```
bs.Filter = String.Format("Status LIKE '*{0}*' AND Customer_Code LIKE '*{1}*' OR Customer_Name LIKE '*{1}*' OR Customer_JobNumber LIKE '*{1}*' OR Customer_Date LIKE '*{1}*' OR Order_Number LIKE '*{1}*'", select, textBox1.Text);
```

Any advice?
Thanks Kindly

Herman Vercuiel

EDIT:

Sorry, probably should have mentioned this is recurring inside a TextChanged Event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to add a couple of parenthesys around your conditions?

```
bs.Filter = String.Format("Status LIKE '*{0}*' AND ( Customer_Code LIKE '*{1}*' " + 
                          "OR Customer_Name LIKE '*{1}*' OR Customer_JobNumber LIKE '*{1}*' " + 
                          "OR Customer_Date LIKE '*{1}*' OR Order_Number LIKE '*{1}*')", 
                          select, textBox1.Text);
```

To mean `STATUS LIKE '*<select>* AND (one or more the following condition is true)`

Comment: Still have to wait 5min to accept your answer. Really shouldve seen that one ey. Well played Steve:)